# how to get user's phone number in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, sim-card

is there a package to get user's phone number for android and ios. I have read some packages like `sim_info` and `sim_data` but as I know there is no property to get user's phone number (please correct me if I am wrong)

Answer (score 1):

There is another package called **[mobile_number](https://pub.dev/packages/mobile_number)**

Note that it doesn't work on iPhone.

If you just want the phone number to fill a form field, you should use:
`autofillHints: [AutofillHints.telephoneNumber}`

Comment: I have tried the example code there ```https://pub.dev/packages/mobile_number/example``` but I still can not get the phone number ```( No phone number on sim card#2
)```, is there any configuration that I should add in MainActivity.kt, the explanation there explain about some code to add inside MainActivity.java. For additional information, I am using android 11 of samsung right now

Comment: The docs say you should only make changes if your project uses a deprecated import of FlutterActivity. If your MainActivity.kt doesnt have it, you should not change anything.

There is an open issue about not being able to get simCard 2 number: https://github.com/amorenew/Flutter-Mobile-Number-Plugin/issues/24

Comment: this plugin doesn't work on all devices